# Creating variables by combining a vector of names and a vector of values

Tags: r, for-loop, variables

I'd like to create a vector/list containing a series of variables that are the result of the combination of two vectors containing (i) specific variable names and (ii) specific variable ID (same for all the variables).
Here are reported a short version of the two vectors:
the variable names:

`names<-c("XPTS", "TROCK", "JFSG")`

and the variable IDs:

`values<-c(1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 2, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 3, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 4, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 5, 5.1, 5.2, 5.3, 6, 6.1, 6.2, 6.3, 7, 7.1, 7.2, 7.3, 8, 8.1, 8.2, 8.3, 9, 9.1, 9.2, 9.3, 10, 10.1, 10.2, 10.3, 11, 11.1, 11.2, 11.3, 12, 12.1, 12.2, 12.3, 13, 13.1, 13.2, 13.3, 14, 14.1, 14.2, 14.3, 15, 15.1, 15.2, 15.3, 16, 16.1, 16.2, 16.3, 17, 17.1, 17.2, 17.3, 18, 18.1, 18.2, 18.3, 19, 19.1, 19.2, 19.3, 20, 20.1, 20.2, 20.3, 21, 21.1, 21.2, 21.3, 22, 22.1, 22.2, 22.3, 23, 23.1, 23.2, 23.3, 24, 24.1, 24.2, 24.3, 25, 25.1, 25.2, 25.3, 26, 26.1, 26.2, 26.3, 27, 27.1, 27.2, 27.3, 28, 28.1, 28.2, 28.3, 29, 29.1, 29.2, 29.3, 30, 30.1, 30.2, 30.3, 31, 31.1, 31.2, 31.3, 32, 32.1, 32.2, 32.3, 33, 33.1, 33.2, 33.3, 34, 34.1, 34.2, 34.3, 35, 35.1, 35.2, 35.3, 36, 36.1, 36.2, 36.3, 37, 37.1, 37.2, 37.3, 38, 38.1, 38.2, 38.3, 39, 39.1, 39.2, 39.3, 40, 40.1, 40.2, 40.3, 41, 41.1, 41.2, 41.3, 42, 42.1, 42.2, 42.3, 43, 43.1, 43.2, 43.3, 44, 44.1, 44.2, 44.3, 45, 45.1, 45.2, 45.3, 46, 46.1, 46.2, 46.3, 47, 47.1, 47.2, 47.3, 48, 48.1, 48.2, 48.3, 49, 49.1, 49.2, 49.3, 50)`

I'd live to obtain a list of variable names as follows:

> "XPTS_1","XPTS_1.1","XPTS_1.2", ..., "XPTS_49.3","XPTS_50","TROCK_1","TROCK_1.1",...,"TROCK_49.3","TROCK_50","JFSG_1","JFSG_1.1",...,"JFSG_49.3","JFSG_50"

The variable names are not only those reported but might change, so I'd like to have a dynamic loop for dealing with it. The one I wrote, as follows, doesn't fit my purpose:

```
variables_ID<-for (i in 1:length(values)) {
  paste(names, values[i], sep = "_")
}
```

since I get only

> "XPTS_50"  "TROCK_50" "JFSG_50"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `outer`

```
out1 <- c(t(outer(names, values, paste, sep="_")))
```

NOTE: `t`ransposed just to show that we get identical results with `rep`

---

Or use `rep` to replicate the 'names' and then `paste`

```
out2 <- paste(rep(names, each = length(values)), values, sep="_")
all.equal(out1, out2)
#[1] TRUE

head(out1)
#[1] "XPTS_1"   "XPTS_1.1" "XPTS_1.2" "XPTS_1.3" "XPTS_2"   "XPTS_2.1"
tail(out1)
#[1] "JFSG_48.3" "JFSG_49"   "JFSG_49.1" "JFSG_49.2" "JFSG_49.3" "JFSG_50"
```

---

Or using `CJ`

```
library(data.table)
CJ(names, values)[, paste(names, values, sep="_")]
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
crossing(names, values) %>%
     unite(names, names, values) %>% 
     pull(names)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice, it is very close to the result I need but it doesn't fulfil my goal properly since I'd need the variable in the order I have them in the vector "names".  I'd actually need them saved as follows:XPTS_1","XPTS_1.1","XPTS_1.2", ..., "XPTS_49.3","XPTS_50","TROCK_1","TROCK_1.1",...,"TROCK_49.3","TROCK_50","JFSG_1","JFSG_1.1",...,"JFSG_49.3","JFSG_50", and not as the ouput of outer ("XPTS_1"     "TROCK_1"    "JFSG_1"     "XPTS_1.1"   "TROCK_1.1"  "JFSG_1.1" etc.)

Comment: @EugenioAlladio  Please check the output.  I get in the same order